# Notifications from custom app page

Tags: development

I have a custom application page with a form and a submit button.
After Submit is clicked some code behind is executed and the user is redirected to the fill-out form again.

I would like to add a Notifcation which appears after the code execution is done so the user knows the updates were done correctly.

Can I use the build in namespace for this (I can not use it in my .cs file anyway)?

```
SP.UI.Notify.addNotification = function(strHtml, bSticky) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about when you redirect the user to fill another form (or the same) then pass the status on the url as a parameter eg: htt://yoursite/Yournewform.aspx?status=Success

And then load you can run javascript to display the notification

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it in your .cs file, but what you can do is add a check in your page for when the page is postback, and if it does then render the javascript syntax for `SP.UI.Notify` in your `CreateChildControls` or `Render` methods.

For more information about `SP.UI.Notify` you should check out [Zevensea's post](http://community.zevenseas.com/Blogs/Robin/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=119).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the page status serverside using the PageStatusSetter.

Comment: Hi Wouter, do you have any examples of this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.sppagestatussetter.aspx